# Ant uses default SMTP port instead of the right one if SSL is activated

Tags: eclipse, ssl, ant

I use Ant within Eclipse to package the compiled code and send it to my storage server via Email. For this I use the following target.
Unfortunately whenever I activate `SSL` the parameter `mailport` is omitted and the standard port 465 is used instead. But the server is actually configured to use port `25` for SSL.

```
<target name="Send mail" depends="zip">
    <echo>Sending mail</echo>
    <mail mailhost="mail.provider.net" password="XXXX" ssl="true" mailport="25" subject="nightly build">
      <from address="me@provider.net"/>
      <replyto address="me@provider.net"/>
      <to address="storage@provider.net"/>
      <message>The nightly build has completed</message>
      <attachments>
        <fileset dir="./src/">
          <include name="src.zip"/>
        </fileset>
      </attachments>
    </mail>
</target>
```

On running I get the following error

> Failed to send email: Could not connect to SMTP host:
>   mail.provider.net, port: 465

On https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49267 from 2010 it's said that there was such a bug in Ant version 1.8.1, fixed in 1.8.2.
I have Eclipse Juno SR2 with Ant v 1.8.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can reopen the [bug](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49267) because:

1. It was [not properly tested by the developper](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49267#c2)
2. Looking at JavaMail source code (the underlying implementation of mail ant task) , I found this:

   `port = PropUtil.getIntSessionProperty(session, "mail." + name + ".port", -1);`
   `//where name is 'smtp' or 'smtps' or ...`
3. Looking at changes related to bug [49267](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/ant/core/trunk/src/main/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/email/MimeMailer.java?r1=943074&r2=943073&pathrev=943074) :

   `props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", String.valueOf(port));`

Conclusion, it seems the patch is wrong and must be:

```
props.put("mail.smtp.port", String.valueOf(port));
```

**EDIT**

Bug [reopened and probably fixed](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49267#c4) now.